# postgresql psql finding percentage window function

Tags: postgresql, percentage, psql, window-functions

Currently using postgresql v. 9.2

I have a table called "mytable" with columns: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday,OTHERCOL,OTHERCOL2,OTHERCOL3,OTHERCOL4:
Column Monday contains : apple, apple, apple **| total(3)**
Column Tuesday contains : strawberry, strawberry, strawberry,strawberry **| total (4)**
Column Wednesday contains: banana, banana **| total (2)** 
Column Thursday contains: orange, orange, orange, orange **| Total (4)**

My question is how would I find the percentage of each column.  For example if I want to find the percentage of column Monday I would want to calculate 3 / 13.  Here, 13 is the total number of fruits, if I were to count each column separately and add them together.

I don't have much experience with postgres and the values are non-integers which makes it more difficult finding a percentage.

I ran into the window function as a possible way of solving this problem.

Are there other ways of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the easiest way, don't use windows functions:

```
SELECT count( Monday )::float
       /
       ( count(Monday)
         + count(Tuesday )
         + count(Wednesday )
         + count( Thursday )
       ) * 100
       As Monday_Percent
FROM mytable
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e295c/3

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what I needed.  If I wanted to combine columns Monday and Tuesday and find the percentage, how would I accomplish such a calculation?

Comment: I actually figured out how to add two columns and their percentage, thanks very helpful!